# Printing and saving base64 encoded image in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dialog

I'm having problems with printing and saving base64 encoded png images from drawing app, which you can see here: http://test1.spletodrom.com/uganka/index.html

In the bottom left you have 2 icons/buttons, Save and Print.
Variable simpleBoard.getImg() is base64 encoded image string.

Save action is triggered by this code:

```
$('#save-img').on('click', function(e) {
  startLoad();
  var img = simpleBoard.getImg();
  img = img.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'slika.png';
  link.target = '_blank';
  link.href = img;
  link.click();
  endLoad();
});
```

Print action is triggered by this code:

```
$('#print-img').on('click', function(e) {
  startLoad();
  var img = simpleBoard.getImg();
  var popup = window.open();
  popup.document.write('<img src=' + img + '>');
  popup.focus(); //required for IE
  popup.print();
  endLoad();
});
```

Browser behaviour:

1. IE9 & IE10:
   click on Save doesn't do anything, click on Print opens base64 encoded image in new tab, but doesn't open print dialog
2. IE11: 
   click on Save or Print opens base64 encoded image in new tab, but doesn't open print/save dialog
3. Firefox: 
   click on Save doesn't do anything, click on Print works properly
4. Chrome: 
   click on Save and Print works properly

There are no errors in console.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've managed to solve Save action with a help of FileSaver.js library: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js (with a compromise of support for IE10+ only)

Comment: The only problem left right now is triggering print dialog in IE.

Comment: I don't understand, why window.print() is not working. I've also tried it through function and onload event, no success.

Comment: I must add that I'm using now IE detection script: https://gist.github.com/esedic/6b1271760d0a4f973547

so I'm trying to change code only for IE

Answer (score 0):

I've combined solutions found here and this is the solution:

```
$('#print-img').on('click', function(e) {
  startLoad();
  var img = simpleBoard.getImg();
  var popup=window.open();
  popup.document.write('<img src=' + img + '>');
  popup.document.close();
  popup.focus();
  popup.print();
  popup.close();
  endLoad();
});
```